# Why does Prometheus resolve unresolved alerts?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have job failure alerts in prometheus, which resolves itself right after 2 hours I got the alert where the alert actually is not resolved. How come Prometheus resolves it? Just so you know, this is only happening with this job alert.

Job Alert:

```
  - alert: Failed Job Status
    expr: increase(kube_job_status_failed[30m]) > 0
    for: 1m
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      identifier: '{{ $labels.namespace }} {{ $labels.job_name }}'
      description: '{{ $labels.namespace }} - {{ $labels.job_name }} Failed'
```

An example of the alert:

```
At 3:01 pm
[FIRING:1] Failed Job Status @ <environment-name> <job-name>
<environment-name> - <job-name> Failed

At 5:01 pm
[RESOLVED]
Alerts Resolved:
- <environment-name> - <job-name>: <environment-name> - <job-name> Failed
```

Here's the related pods as it can be seen that nothing seems to be resolved.

[image: Scription here]

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by it's actually not resolved? Are job failures continuing to happen? It doesn't look like it from the screenshot

Comment: @JasonS I am referring to `job4`, `job5` and `job6`. The other jobs were successfully run due to other changes. Those are failures.

Comment: Should I not receive any resolved alerts for job4, job5, and job6? Am I wrong? @JasonS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kube_job_status_failed` is a gauge representing the number of failed job pods at a given time. The expression `increase(kube_job_status_failed[30m]) > 0` asks the question: "have there been new failures in the last 30 minutes?" If there haven't, it won't be true, even if old failures remain in the Kubernetes API.

A refinement of this approach is `sum(rate(kube_job_status_failed[5m])) by (namespace, job_name) > 0`, plus an alert manager configuration to *not send resolved notices* for this alert. This is because a job pod failure is an event that can't be reversed - the job could be retried, but the pod can't be un-failed so resolution only means the alert has "aged out" or the pods have been deleted.

An expression that looks at the current number of failures recorded in the API server is `sum(kube_job_status_failed) by (namespace, job_name) > 0`. An alert based on this could be "resolved", but only by the `Job` objects being removed from the API (which doesn't necessarily mean that a process has succeeded...)